# Programmatically navigate to iOS main settings app, not the app specific settings page

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, appsettings, settings.bundle

I have this code snippet that will open my app specific settings screen.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

But I want the user to be taken to the main iPhone Settings screen instead of app specific screen. I have been searching for this over the last few days and not able to find a way. Is it possible to do this navigation?

Comment: You can't open main iPhone Settings

Comment: I tried with a simple app that doesn't have any app specific settings and the user is navigated to the main settings screen. I was thinking if there is any way to simulate something like that or any workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in Swift and It took me to main settings screen.

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

Comment: It's only happen when your app setting is not showing in Setting list like other app.